# Create the GlobalVariable which have extern in one header file

Tags: llvm

Good day. I am facing an issue with creating a GlobalVariable. I already have an extern for that global in a header file to use it in the following way

```
extern const void* DATA_TABLE[];
```

And with a LLVM PASS, I am trying to create this array with the same name and with an initializer. So, I have the following:

```
GlobalVariable *gvar_data = new GlobalVariable(
    M, blockItems->getType(), true, GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,
    blockItems, "DATA_TABLE");
gvar_data->setAlignment(16);
gvar_data->setSection("data_section");
gvar_data->addAttribute(llvm::Attribute::OptimizeNone);
```

I am not sure if I am using the correct Linkage or not.
The pass has failed to complete it. Here is the runtime fault. Any guess what I am doing incorrect?

```
'common' global must have a zero initializer!
[10 x i8*]* @DATA_TABLE.1
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted:::::::::!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call [setInitializer()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#a095f8f031d99ce3c0b25478713293dea), the GlobalVariable you make is extern. There is a function that'll supply an all-zeroes initializer for a type you supply, I don't remember its name off-hand, or you can make a suitable initializer yourself using classes such as [ConstantStruct](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantStruct.html#a54ff81b5ee471f3384943bcaf9be7162), ConstantInt and their siblings.

Comment: `blockItems` is the initializer, so it should not be extern.

Comment: And what's why you have to call setInitializer().

Comment: the setInitializer() is called internally by GlobalVariable()